# Difference between next() and hasNext() in java collections

Tags: java, collections

I am new to java and I was going through collections and during the iteration they have used `next()` and `hasNext()` methods. What exactly does these two methods do? When do I have to use `next()` and `hasNext()`?

Comment: did you read the docs?

Comment: [next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--), [hasNext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--).

Comment: They are completely different methods... I honestly find it difficult to believe that anyone could possibly confuse the two.

Comment: next() and hasNext() of which API? Java have lots of it in different API

Comment: next() will return next value in collection. hashnext() return the next value existance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hasNext()` will return true if iteration has more values and 
`next()` will return the next element in iteration

Comment: what is the difference between next() and nextTag() ?

Answer (score 8):

**hasNext()** : hasNext() method returns true if iterator have more elements.

**next()**    : next() method returns the next element and also moves cursor pointer to the next element.

Comment: how do we know that `next()` moves cursor pointer to the next element?  I didn't see this in the documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**hasNext()** - Returns true if the iteration has more elements.

**next()** - Returns the next element in the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

HasNext() : if we are using hasNext() with the while loop for traversing in a collection then it returns a boolean value.

hasNext() method check is there any element left in a row if yes then it returns true and if not then it returns false and the pointer goes out the loop.

while the next() method retruns the value of the next element in a row

Comment: I think it is confusing to say hasNext() points anywhere. The OP is a beginner and this is a basic question, so you need to be very very clear in your response. Try adding an example.

Answer (score 0):

`hasNext()`- "Returns true if the iteration has more elements"
So you can check if there are more objects you can get from the iterator, and if there are it returns true. If there are no more objects it will return false.

`next()` - "Returns the next element in the iteration"
So if there is a next item, it will be returned. If there isn't it'll throw a 'NoSuchElementException', but if you use iterators properly you should never encounter it.